# Python - Pandas - Import Excel file, iterate through each row, add new value, and add to dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops, import-from-excel

I have an Excel file with a project code and abstract fields I need to import so I can run a simple text summarizer on the abstract and then add to the dataframe.

My Excel dataset looks like this:

```
[Proj_Number] | [Abstract]

JJF-123          | Diabetes is a serious chronic condition.  
JFR-223          | Cardiovascular disease is also a chronic condition. 
JF3-334          | Don't forget about asthma and how much it sucks.
```

once I import the data, I want to apply my text summarizer and get this:

```
[Proj_Number] | [Abstract]                        [Ab_keywords]

JJF-123       | Diabetes is a chronic condition.  |Diabetes, chronic condition                                                                 
JFR-223       | COPD is a also chronic condition. | COPD, chronic condition
JF3-334       | Don't forget about asthma too.    | asthma, forgot
```

I know my code is wrong, but I just don't know how to loop through each row, get the abstract keywords from the abstract, add it to the dataframe, and export it.

```py
from gensim.summarization.summarizer import summarize
from gensim.summarization import keywords
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_excel('abstracts.xlsx',encoding="ISO-8859-1")
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
cols = [1,2]
df = df[df.columns[cols]]

for d in df:
d =  keywords(d, ratio=0.15, split=True))
print(d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont want to iterate over every row in the df with `for d in df:`

Pandas has a way of applying a function to each row of a dataframe and returning a series via the `apply` function

Providing you rename the columns of your dataframe appropriately,

`df['Ab_keywords'] = df['Abstract'].apply(lambda text: keywords(text, ratio=0.15, split=True))`

should work.

Here the lambda function is applied to each row of `df['Abstract']` and is given the value of each row as its argument.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've replaced the for d in df: section with the code you added and got "KeyError: 'Abstract'" - any thoughts? I revised my code above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, ugh, I was calling the wrong column.  Your code worked, thanks!

Comment: Great, can you leave the original question as it was in case anyone else comes across the same issue?